# node.js fonts not working properly and showing no errors

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, fonts

I'm trying to build a website that uses custom fonts but when I try to use them nothing happens.

My files are laid out like this:

https://gyazo.com/5ee766f030290e5b2fa42320cc39f10b

My CSS file:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'anuratiregular';
src: url('public/css/fonts/Anurati-Regular.otf') format('otf'),
     url('public/css/fonts/Anurati-Regular.otf') format('otf');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'onedayregular';
    src: url('public/css/fonts/ONEDAY.otf') format('otf'),
         url('public/css/fonts/ONEDAY.otf') format('otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

.section-1-header {
    font-family: anuratiregular;
}
```

My JS file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

//Starts the server and allows it to Listen
//on port 3000 for any traffic

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Listening on Port 3000");
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//delivers index.html file when people navigate
//to the root page

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/index.html");
});
```

Here is how I am including the CSS file in my HTML. Other styles are applying properly so it should be fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
```

I get this error in my dev tools:

> GET http://localhost:3000/css/public/css/fonts/Anurati-Regular.otf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) :3000/css/public/css/fonts/Anurati-Regular.otf:1

Comment: We will, of course, need to see how you include the CSS file in your HTML file. But one of the best ways to see what's going on is to press F12, go to the network tab, and then refresh the page (F5). This will show you if your font file is loading correctly (404 famously is not found, 200 is what you want to see). Also, not sure why you have duplicate lines in the src portion.

Comment: After changing the OTF format to opentype like Bauke said I startet getting the 404 error (Ill post it in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `src` formats are incorrect, `.otf` files use `format('opentype')`. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face):

> The available types are: "woff", "woff2", "truetype", "opentype", "embedded-opentype", and "svg".

Comment: After changing it to opentype I started getting the 404 error i added to the question above

Comment: Your `url()` is relative to where the CSS file is, so you need to adjust it to `fonts/<font>.otf`, instead of `public/css/fonts/...`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate web font from that otf file. Use online tool like
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
or
https://everythingfonts.com/font-face. There only you will get a specimen files where the generated fonts files and css file you will get. Copy the css from the css file and place the font files in the correct path as css path.